# Python global variable not found when using OOP

Tags: python, oop

Now I have the problem with the global variable that defined but when run the class object, it raises the error of "The 'variable' is not defined

Specifically,

1. I have created a file called `__init__.py` which contains global variables
2. Create the `class_0.py`, contain the function which uses defined variable in `__init__.py`
3. Create the `class_1.py`, to combine things which also run the function in `class_0.py`

`__init__.py`

```
asset = {'abc': 123, ...}
cost = {...}
```

`class_0.py`

```
from __init__ import *
class defc():
    def function(self):
        a = asset['abc']
        return ...
```

`class_1.py`

```
from __init__ import *
from class_0 import *
class run_main():
    def __init__(self):
       self.defc = defc()
    def run(self):
       self.defc.function()
```

Then it raises the Error

> NameError: name 'asset' is not defined

So how to solve this problem? the `asset` variable is the very long dictionary and I don't want to put it in a specific `class` due to there still other `class` use this.

Comment: You should know that `__init__.py` is no longer required in python 3.3+

Comment: @snatchysquid so how to fix my problem?

Comment: @ShanN You solution works for me, [try it online here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64074008#main.py). Are you using newest version of Python 3? Or if you're using `jupyter` try resetting notebook.

Comment: Depending on your file layout, you may need to make clear that the import is local by prepending a dot (e.g. `from .__init__ import ...`). Also, it would be better to use some other module like `constants.py` instead of `__init__.py`, though that does not change the semantics.

Answer (score -3):

Save all your work and try restarting your kernel.